# Javascript check form amounts match within +/- 0.10

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

This script checks that the amount of the purchase order is entered correctly vs the amount calculated by the line items. The issue I have is that it's too accurate. I need to allow for small variances due to items that are priced by weight. I need to allow for at least $0.10 difference.

Also. Once the script is triggered and informs the user that the amounts don't match, the user can no longer submit the form without refreshing the page.

```
<script>
function validateTotals()
{
var amount_incorrect = false;

var u=document.forms["complete_purchase_order"]["total_cost_original"].value;
if (u!=<cfoutput>#NumberFormat(po_total_original, '99999.99')#</cfoutput>)
  {
    amount_incorrect = true;
  }

var v=document.forms["complete_purchase_order"]["total_cost_received"].value;
if (v!=<cfoutput>#NumberFormat(po_total_received,'99999.99')#</cfoutput>)
  {
    amount_incorrect = true;
  }

if (amount_incorrect)
  {
   alert('Incorrect Original/Received Total');
   return false;
  }

}
</script>
```

EDIT: To clear things up. The user enters purchase order details line by line. The line totals are calculated, and then the PO total is calculated.

In some instances, the quantity will be up to two decimal points. 
Example: Qty 8.15 x Price 4.15 = 33.8225. I round to the nearest penny 33.82.

The slight difference on how we do the addition vs how the supplier does, will leave a difference of about 1 to 2 cents for the entire PO. Worse case scenario, 10 cents. I would like the order to be completed even if the PO amount from what we received VS what they sent differs by +/- 10 cents.

Using Coldfusion to resolve this issue for now. I would much rather prefer not having the form submit before checking the values.

```
    <cfif #FORM.total_cost_original# NEQ #po_total_original# OR #FORM.total_cost_received# NEQ #po_total_received#>
        <cfif #FORM.total_cost_original# LT (#po_total_original# - .10) OR #FORM.total_cost_original# GT (#po_total_original# + .10)
                OR #FORM.total_cost_received# LT (#po_total_received# - .10) OR #FORM.total_cost_received# GT (#po_total_received# + .10)>
```

This will abort the script and redirect the user back to the form page.

Comment: @Oriol That's ColdFusion syntax. It looks like it may be correct.

Comment: @user3556177 A wise man once told me to always do math on currency in cents. That avoids the rounding issue. It isn't hard to do and it has always been a good choice.

Comment: Don't really see a question here. Please add what you expect to happen, what is actually happening and what you have tried to fix the issue.

Comment: Your code isn't doing any comparison between `u` and `v`. What have you  tried?  You could do the math in cents as suggested earlier, and just subtract u and v and test the values are in the range you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
if (
       !(
             u <= <cfoutput>#NumberFormat(po_total_original+0.10, '99999.99')#</cfoutput> 
          && u >= <cfoutput>#NumberFormat(po_total_original-0.10, '99999.99')#</cfoutput>
        )
   )
```

You can do same for variable `v`.

Comment: To make it cleaner, how about just 
if( abs( u - <cfoutput>#NumberFormat(po_total_original, '99999.99')#</cfoutput> ) <= .10 )